# I apparently inappropriately flagged a good question as opinion based

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the First Posts queue and was given this question as a test: [Python for loop better way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46996315/1166898)

I flagged it as "Should be closed - primarily opinion based". I got feedback saying:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.** Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

I disagree. The question title includes "better" (opinion) and the body asks:

> So my question is, **why** does not Python encourage such usage if the second method is much more efficient ? Is there a **better** way ?

(emphasis mine)

Questions about the speed of this tiny thing versus that tiny thing are usually prematurely optimising.

I don't see how this can be anything other than opinion based. I stand by my evaluation, unless someone can show me otherwise.

Comment: Well, the answer is "Yes, there's a better way", and it's based on timing, and includes an explanation of why it's faster. It may be premature optimization, or it may not, depending on context, but it isn't a question of opinion. You're still free to downvote for any reason, of course.

Comment: Don't flag based on key words. Evaluate the *substance* of the post. The word "better" doesn't make a question automatically opinion-based, and the inclusion of a link doesn't automatically make an answer "link-only".

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**: The question is poorly titled and perhaps poorly worded in some parts, but the *meat* of the question is good.

---

The question is not actually about which way is "better" for looping. If you read through it in detail, it's actually a question about why certain styles of looping seem to have a significant performance advantage over the others. It then goes on to ask if there are even more efficient ways. In other words, it's a well researched, specific question about the behavior of some specific language constructs, even if it wasn't explained the most clearly.

Note that a user knowledgeable in Python was able to propose an even faster method that is still idiomatic. If someone familiar with the subject matter can provide a good answer, this often indicates it was a good question to begin with.

While in many cases this may be premature optimization, understanding the performance characteristics of your code is sometimes vital. It really depends. Questions where the user asks sort of "in isolation" aren't forbidden as long as the question makes a clear statement about what it's trying to achieve, although you may wish to comment asking if there's a particular use case they have or if this was idle curiosity. In this case, the user isn't asking a question that's out in left field crazy and totally against the norms of the language; wanting a loop repeated a specific number of times to be fast is a situation you might reasonably run into during development.

In this particular case, editing to try to clear up the presentation would probably have been the most appropriate thing to do. So take the advice: slow down. Don't make a judgement based on title alone. Read the question thoroughly and ask yourself whether a good question is buried somewhere in there or not.